# Category and Product mapping in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

With RoR ORM, how would you map this model.

```
Categories
-id

Products
-id

CategoriesProducts
-category_id
-product_id
```

So I want to perform queries like:

```
category.products.all
product.category.id
```

In rails, how do you decide which side of the relationship will be used for adding products to a category?

Will it be like:

```
category.add_product(product)
```

or

```
product.add_category(category)
```

And what if I wanted to fetch all categories with id 234,24,431,214 and products, is there a way I could do this w/o running into a n+1 query issue?

Comment: All of your questions are answered in detail in the [Ruby on Rails guide for Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 9):

Simplest way to do it, use `has_and_belongs_to_many`.  Make sure that when creating the CategoriesProucts table, you have the migration file create without an id:

```
create_table :categories_products, :id => false do |t|
```

Then your cateogry model should look like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

And your Product model should look like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Here's another method.  This would also work if you wanted to have some more control for modification later.  On your CategoriesProduct model:

```
class CategoriesProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
end
```

On your Categories model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories_products
  has_many :products, :through => :categories_products
end
```

On your product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories_products
  has_many :categories, :through => :categories_products
end
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
Category.create(:name => "Cat1")
Category.first.products.create(:name => "Prod1")
Product.first.categories.create(:name => "Cat2")
```

etc...

[This infograph](http://mboffin.com/stuff/ruby-on-rails-data-relationships.png) may be helpful in visualizing the concept.

Comment: is categoriesproducts suppose to be a model or isn't that just a join table?

Comment: I interpreted your description as that you were using `categoriesproducts` as a join table.  Couldn't you just put a `category_id` field on the `Product` model and then have the relationship I described at the end of my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Create a table categories_products, categories, and products, and create modal for Category and Products.

Have the relationship has_and_belongs_to_many in both the modals. This should give allow you to use methods like @category.products (to get all products, for a particular category) and @product.categories (to get all categories for that product).

Also look at these:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many

Answer (score 1):

In terms of deciding how to get the data back again it is really up to you and what angle your coming at the data from.

For instance, in a categories_controller it will make more sense to come through categories to products, and vice versa for products.

To get all products for certain categories you can combine this:

```
Category.where("id IN (?)", [1,2,3,4,5,6]).includes(:products)
```

(or similar, I've not tested this).  This will do one query for Categories, and one for the products.